# How to use cookies to allow a modal dialog to only be fired once? After a week the modal can be fired again

Tags: jquery, cookies, modal-dialog

I'm looking to use cookies to only allow the modal dialog to be seen once until a week has past. Essentially the modal would fire once the document has loaded and after it's closed there will be an expiration set for a 7 days until it will fire again.

$( document ).ready(function() {

```
var element = $('.md-modal'),
    close = $('.md-close');

element.addClass('md-show');

$(close).one('click', function() {
    element.removeClass('md-show');
    $(close).off()
});
```

});

Could someone please help with a little direction on using cookies for this execution?

Thanks!

Will

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (getCookie("modalShow") != "1"){
    //Show Modal
    setCookie("modalShow","1", 7);
}

function setCookie(strName, strValue, expireDays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (expireDays * 604800000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = strName + "=" + strValue + "; " + expires + "; path=/";
}

function getCookie(strName) {
    var name = strName + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i].trim();
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```

In the first block check the cookie and if we don't have a cookie with name:modalShow and value:1 then show modal and set a cookie with this name and value and a 7 days period for expiration.
After 7 days the cookie is expired automatically and the modal is shown again.